# Python NameError: name 'N' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is Python (3.8) throwing NameError when using class variables? The following works fine,

```
class Tester(object):
    # Number of measurements
    N = 6
    temp = [ 0. for x in range(N) ]
```

However when I try to use it as follows, it gives NameError.

```
class Tester(object):
    # Number of measurements
    N = 6
    temp = [[ 0. for x in range(N) ] for y in range(N) ]
```

It seems to be happening for the first N.
So something like `temp = [[ 0. for x in range(6) ] for y in range(N) ]` works fine.

When I replace `N` by `Tester.N`, it gives `NameError` for `Tester`, which makes sense since the class is not defined.

How can I define the temp which is a 2-D list?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your approach doesn't work. If you add it to the **init** it works:

```
class Tester(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # Number of measurements
        N = 6
        temp = [[ 0. for x in range(N) ] for y in range(N) ]
        print(temp)

tester = Tester()
```